# dot product of complex vectors

Tags: complex-analysis

I select vectors 4 orthogonal vectors $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4 \in \mathbb{C}^4$. I have a random matrix $B \in \mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$. Now, this matrix $B$ rotates the vector $P_1$ to a new vector $P_1^{H}B$, which will not be orthogonal with any of the original 4 vectors by the assumption of $B$ is random. My question is weather it is possible to select the norms(lengths) of the orthogonal vectors $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ such that their inner product with the new vector $P_1^{H}B$ is the same, i.e., $P_1^{H}B P_1=P_1^{H}B P_2=P_1^{H}B P_3=P_1^{H}B P_4$.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your notation, but since the inner product is linear (or anti-linear, depending on your convention and meaning) and you're willing to replace $P_j$ by $\lambda_j P_j$ for some complex numbers $\lambda_j$ (for $j = 2$, $3$, $4$), the answers appears (trivially) to be "yes". In fact, this argument works provided $P_1^HBP_j \neq 0$ for $1 \leq j \leq 4$.

Comment: I understand that the answer us trivial when Pi in R, but the problem is that they are in C, where I don't get the intuition of the inner product very well over the space of complex numbera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [user86418 said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603675/dot-product-of-complex-vectors#comment1271649_603675), the answer is yes. Begin with any $P_1,\dots,P_4$ as above, and then define new vectors $P_1',\dots,P_4$ by $P_1'=P_1$,
$$P_k' = \frac{P_1^HBP_1}{P_1^HBP_k}P_k,\quad k=2,3,4$$